# PHP Calling a model method multiple times with having different value for parameter in codeiginter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I created a method in the model to get data from the database and then call it in the controller for multiple time with different method parameters($param) values. This is working for only one parameter value which one comes first. I Know i am doing it in wrong way but i am unable to find the solution for this. please help.

**Actually, I am trying to have category based on their type('wordpress', 'magento', 'shopify') form database**

My_model.php

```
class My_model extends CI_Model{

  public function fun_name($param){
       return $this->db->get_where('categories', array('type' => '$param'));
  }

}
```

My_controller.php

```
class My_controller extends CI_Controller{
   public function get_data(){
       $this->load->model('my_model');
       $data = array(
           'first'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('wordpress'),
           'second'  =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('magento'),
           'third'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('shopify')
        );
       $this->load->view('index', $data);
   }
}
```

Comment: can you print_r($data) for me please?

Comment: Is that actual code you are executing?

Comment: I am assuming you are just "testing" out some principles here. Using a conditional with a fixed value on your model, as it stands, isn't very useful.

Comment: sorry guys, the condition in model if($param = one){},  i make it by mistake. This is not the actual code but the thing is that i want value for all three            'first'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('first'),
           'second'  =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('sec'),
           'third'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('third')

Comment: Actually, I am trying to have category based on their type('wordpress', 'magento', 'shopslick') form database

Answer (score 1):

If that's your actual code,

```
class My_model extends CI_Model{
  public function fun_name($param){
    if($param = one){
       return $this->db->get_where('table', array('id' => '$param'));
    }
  }
}
```

then the issue is in this line below -

```
    if($param = one){
```

change it to

```
    if($param == 'one'){
```

.

and in this

```
return $this->db->get_where('table', array('id' => '$param'));
```

change it to this line below because you don't need quotes around variable

```
return $this->db->get_where('table', array('id' => $param));
```

Obviously your code can be optimised better i.e. you may not need if - else the way you are doing but again without knowing the full scenario it's not easy to recommend a solution.

Comment: Why would you do if($param = 'one'){ ? You are assigning 'one' to $param. To do a comparision you need ==, i.e. if($param == 'one'){

Comment: that was typo which i meant to correct. Updated now.

Comment: The whole IF statement isn't even required. There's no point to having it there.

Comment: I don't know. One step at a time. If OP asks for if he's trying to get rid of iFs I can take a look at alternative options

Comment: More aimed at the OP, but yeah I know how that is - where do you stop?

Comment: sorry guys, the condition in model if($param = one){},  i make it by mistake. This is not the actual code but the thing is that i want value for all the three
            'first'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('first'),
           'second'  =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('sec'),
           'third'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('third')

Comment: Actually, I am trying to have category based on their type('wordpress', 'magento', 'shopslick') form database

Comment: @TimBrownlaw, you r real good in this man, where everybody try solve my typo mistake, you found out that it's not even required

Comment: Nah, just another set of blurry eyes passing over it... It's easy to miss things like that. And you have to remember that initially - the reasons for some code that gets shown isn't fully explained and the subtle details come out in the wash later on... But the = vs == was glaringly obvious so it had to be mentioned. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select different ids from the same table using one query then you can do something like following:

Model:

```
class My_model extends CI_Model{

  public function fun_name($params){
    $this->db->where_in('id', $params);
    return $this->db->get('table');
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
class My_controller extends CI_Controller{
   public function get_data(){
       $this->load->model('my_model');
       $params = array('first', 'sec', 'third');
       $data['values'] = $this->my_model->fun_name($params);

       $this->load->view('index', $data);
   }
}
```

You can also see the Codeigniter documentation: 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Comment: sorry, the condition in model if($param = one){},  i make it by mistake. This is not the actual code but the thing is that i want value for all three            'first'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('first'),
           'second'  =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('sec'),
           'third'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('third')

Comment: Actually, I am trying to have category based on their type('wordpress', 'magento', 'shopslick') form database

Answer (score 1):

How about changing

```
if($param = 'one'){
```

to

```
if($param == 'one'){
```

Comment: sorry, the condition in model if($param = one){},  i make it by mistake. This is not the actual code but the thing is that i want value for all three            'first'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('first'),
           'second'  =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('sec'),
           'third'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('third')

Comment: Actually, I am trying to have category based on their type('wordpress', 'magento', 'shopslick') form database

Answer (score 1):

Can you try?

your controller

```
class My_controller extends CI_Controller{
   public function get_data(){
       $this->load->model('my_model');
       $data['data'] = array(
           'first'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('param1'),
           'second'  =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('param2'),
           'third'   =>   $this->my_model->fun_name('param3')
        );
       $this->load->view('index', $data);
   }
}
```

model

```
class My_model extends CI_Model{

  public function fun_name($param){
       return $this->db->get_where('categories', array('type' => $param))->row()->category_name;
  }

}
```

view

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>type</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $i++;
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: thanx for your contribution i have tried the same way but its something wrong with my code, first i was thinking that i am doing it in wrong way but worked when i tried it on new ci, i have to look for the issue